# scala validate password and confirm password in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

```
val userForm = Form[Info](
    mapping(
      "first name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "last name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> email,

      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
  "confirm_password" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(
    "password don't match", confirm_password=> confirm_password  == "1234"
  )
    ) (Info.apply)(Info.unapply)
  )
```

**1234** is just **hardcode** one, i want to add the password parameter to that place. **how to do that?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `verifying` and compare `password` and `confirmPassword`

```
  import play.api.data.Forms._
  import play.api.data.Form

  case class Info(
    first: String,
    last: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    confirmPass: String)

  val userForm = Form[Info](
    mapping(
      "first name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "last name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> email,

      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
      "confirm_password" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(
        "password don't match", confirm_password => confirm_password  == "1234"
      )
    ) (Info.apply)(Info.unapply).verifying("Password and Confirm password does not match", info => info.password == info.confirmPass)
  )
```

Comment: Yep it is checking password and confirm password is equal or not but error message is not appear when the values aren't equal

Comment: Error message is with global errors . Check global errors documentation on play scala docs

Comment: i removed password verification from here and  i applied it into controller. then it worked. (validating password and confirm password and displaying error message)

Comment: It is not my question, only @RukshanWithanage can do that.